# How to refill file input after form submited with errors

Tags: php, forms

I have an

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="file" name="photo">
```

After submit it form, I found some errors, so, I do:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
<input type="file" name="photo" value="WHAT HERE?!">
```

As you can see, I don't know what I need to write on the value attr to refill the selected file form the user.
Can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done because it presents too many security risks. When a file is uploaded, the browser is not given the actual file path but rather creates a temporary file (with a path value of C:\fakepath) that it can send to the server on processing. So there is no value you can pass through the POST that you can put back into an input to choose a file.

An alternative would be to use AJAX for form validation, that way the user never leaves the page until the form is ready to submit.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do that?

No, you cant. For security reasons, the value attribute is ignored for input elements
of `type="file"`.

Possible workarounds:

- Keep a reference to the submitted file (that is stored on disk) in a hidden input. Show a message to the user to inform that the file not need to be entered again, because you already have it from previous failed submits.
- Submit your form via AJAX.
- Validate as much as possible on the client side with javascript to avoid reloads. This will assume javascript is enabled.

Comment: On the first workaround, when you say "keep a reference to the submitted file (that is stored on disk)", do you refer to the temporary file stored on the server?